# How to Avoid Injecting User Object Throughout my Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a project where I have embedded a JWT in the header of all calls to my RESTful web services.  The JWT includes all relevant user information (name, username, roles, etc...) and each of my WEB API controllers pulls it from the session headers and makes it available as a local private variable for use in endpoint specific authorization.

But I need this information not just at the RESTful endpoints, I need it with each call to my database (auditing).  Only, it doesn't seem elegant to pass the user object into every call and have those calls pass it along in its calls too.

Ultimately, I have an auditing component that is embedded in the guts of EF which logs every call to and from the database.  I want the user object attached to that so I have a clear audit trail which includes not just what was changed, but who changed it...

Is there a way to make my user object (which is grabbed by the constructor of the WEB API controller) available to everything that may need it without injecting it into each call?

*Session would have worked nicely, but the services are RESTful and subsequently, session is not available.

Comment: You should be able to attach it to the `HttpContext` in each request.  Check out `HttpContext.Current.Items`.

Comment: We're trying that.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: HttpContext doesn't scale well to the lower layers, which are not necessarily web related. I usually use an IoC container (Autofac, LightInject) to inject the user info in one form or another in the lower layers, as a member of one or more base classes which would be instantiated per request in your case. Alternatively, you could use a Func for similar purposes, without an IoC container. It's much cleaner that way.